# Android - View animation while transition animation is still running

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, activity-transition

Activity B starts and pushes Activity A to the left. This transition takes 200ms and I implement this calling this method in onCreate() before setContentView()

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right_to_left, R.anim.slide_out_right_to_left);
```

What I want to achieve is to start animating UI elements in the contentView at 100ms...So that the whole animation has a continuous feel. I haven't found where in the code I should start animating the UI elements.